# How to open, edit and push back an xml stream with perl?

Tags: xml, perl, dom, xml-parsing, libxml2

I was wondering if it was possible with perl to open, modify the DOM and save a XML file with only one stream. I am trying to accomplish that with XML::LibXML but no succes until now.

I would like to get an Element via XPath and then modify some attributes or the text value.
I would like to append child to an element got with an XPath expression, etc ... But working with one and only one stream if possible.

And once everything modified push it back to original file.

Any Module that can do that ?

Comment: I found this site http://www.wellho.co.uk/resources/ex.php4?item=p668/goblin.pl that showed me how to alternate my XML stream with  XML::LibXML

Comment: I'm not sure "stream" is the best description. Streaming XML is usually involving connections to remote systems, and XML::Stream supports that nicely. Could be a little clearer about what you mean by "only one stream"?

Comment: By stream I meant the content of the file, but my translation to english was erronous. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, XML::LibXML does not support any streaming at all, it always reads and parses the whole document first.

Usually [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aTwig) is recommended instead, but I don't know if it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

XML::Twig using the XPath class looks like it would be handy.  But this sounds a bit like a job for an XSLT stylesheet.  I guess it depends on the xml file you are handling though...